# R Subsetting IDs that contain multiple keywords

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

I need to subset my data frame based on whether the ID contains a pair of keywords. The data I have looks like this:

```
Keyword  | ID
CVa      | 1
CVa      | 2
CVa      | 6
TST      | 3 
TST      | 3 
TST      | 2 
TST      | 2 
TST      | 4 
TST      | 5 
QFT      | 1
QFT      | 3 
QFT      | 6
```

I need to subset such that all the rows that have keyword pairings of CVa and TST OR CVa and QFT are left. So, for example, I would want all rows for ID's 1, 2 and 6.

This is what I have right now, but it's not combining the keywords the way I need it to.

```
CVaSubset <- subset(CleanKeys, subset = (CleanKeys$keyword == 'CVa' | CleanKeys$keyword == 'TST' | Cleankeys$keyword == 'QFT')
```

It's subsetting but I'm not getting the combination I need.  I also tried:

```
CVaSubset <- subset(CleanKeys, subset = ( (CleanKeys$keyword == 'CVa' & CleanKeys$keyword == 'TST') |(CleanKeys$keyword == 'CVa' & Cleankeys$keyword == 'QFT')
```

I think I'm missing a group_by statement but I don't know how to get the combination of the two keywords.

Edit:

I processed this code on a comprehensive dataset that included many other keywords and received the error:

```
"Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist. x Columns CFC, CFC, CFC, CFC, CFC, etc. don't exist."
```

I fixed this issue, but now I'm getting the error after the filter step:

```
x operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types
```

But, some of my keywords are hyphenated, so I think this is the issue. I put the names in ``, I'm hoping this will solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to filter your data according to your specifications if
your data is organized in a “tidy” fashion. Meaning that each case, represented
by a unique `ID` value, is in one row.

We can achieve that with `tidyr::pivor_wider()`.
`pivot_wider()` needs a column to draw variable names for the wide format from, and
another column to draw values from. Your data only has the column for the names (`Keyword`).
With `dplyr::mutate()` we create a dummy variable that is TRUE for each row. By specifying
the `values_fill` argument of `pivot_wider()` as `FALSE`, each cell that
represents a case where the keyword is not present will be populated with a
`FALSE`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
tidy_data <-
  data %>%
  unique() %>%
  mutate(dummy = TRUE) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = ID,
    names_from = Keyword,
    values_from = dummy,
    values_fill = FALSE
  )

tidy_data
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>      ID CVa   TST   QFT  
#>   <int> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
#> 1     1 TRUE  FALSE TRUE 
#> 2     2 TRUE  TRUE  FALSE
#> 3     6 TRUE  FALSE TRUE 
#> 4     3 FALSE TRUE  TRUE 
#> 5     4 FALSE TRUE  FALSE
#> 6     5 FALSE TRUE  FALSE
```

Now we can easily filter the data the way you describe.

With `dplyr::filter()`:

```r
tidy_data %>%
  filter((CVa & TST) | (CVa & QFT))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>      ID CVa   TST   QFT  
#>   <int> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
#> 1     1 TRUE  FALSE TRUE 
#> 2     2 TRUE  TRUE  FALSE
#> 3     6 TRUE  FALSE TRUE
```

Or `base::subset()`

```r
subset(tidy_data, (CVa & TST) | (CVa & QFT))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>      ID CVa   TST   QFT  
#>   <int> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
#> 1     1 TRUE  FALSE TRUE 
#> 2     2 TRUE  TRUE  FALSE
#> 3     6 TRUE  FALSE TRUE
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much, but I'm getting an error pertaining to some of they keywords I don't care about: 
Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Columns `CFC`, `CFC`, `CFC`, `CFC`, `CFC`, etc. don't exist.

Comment: Do you get that error when you execute the code on the data used in your question or when you apply it to another/full dataset? After which command do you get that error? Please edit your original question to reflect this issue.

Comment: I updated it, I think the issue may be stemming from the keyword names being hyphenated.

Comment: Can you please include a data example that leads to that issue in your question? Also please add the code you have tried. And please also share the code of what you did to fix the first issue.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to identify all `ID` in `Cleankeys` which contain either *both* keywords `CVa` and `TST` or *both* keywords `CVa` and `QFT`. Then, the OP wants to subset `Cleankeys` using the identified `ID`s.

Instead of hardcoding the conditions, the required pairs of keywords can be defined in a data file:

```
# Required keyword pairings
pairs <- readr::read_table("
Keyword1 Keyword2
CVa      TST
CVa      QFT")
```

Note that the keyword pairs must be given in row-wise sorted order, i.e., each row fulfills the condition `Keyword1 < Keyword2`. This data file can be extended arbitrarily to contain as many keyword pairs as necessary.

Now, we can create all possible combinations of keyword pairs for each `ID` in `CleanKeys` and compare this with the required keyword pairings. Then, those IDs which have a keyword pair which appears in the required keyword pairings are used to subset `CleanKeys`:

```
library(dplyr)
CleanKeys %>% 
  inner_join(x = ., y = ., by = "ID", suffix = c("1", "2")) %>% 
  filter(Keyword1 < Keyword2) %>% 
  right_join(pairs) %>% 
  select(ID) %>% 
  arrange() %>% 
  unique() %>% 
  left_join(CleanKeys)
```

> ```
>      ID Keyword
>   <dbl> <chr>  
> 1     1 CVa    
> 2     1 TST    
> 3     1 QFT    
> 4     2 CVa    
> 5     2 TST    
> 6     6 CVa    
> 7     6 QFT
> ```

#### Data

```
CleanKeys <- readr::read_delim("
Keyword  | ID
CVa      | 1
CVa      | 2
CVa      | 6
TST      | 3 
TST      | 3 
TST      | 1 
TST      | 2 
TST      | 4 
TST      | 5 
QFT      | 1
QFT      | 3 
QFT      | 6", 
delim = "|", trim_ws = TRUE)
```

Comment: That is correct, I am trying to return the values that overlap. Is there an inherent problem with hardcoding the values? Other than the need to change it every time I change my subsetting parameters?

Comment: @MeredithAbrams No, there is no inherent problem with hardcoding. On the other hand, I have learned that it might be worthwhile to make things flexible & configurable. And it's about separating rules and structures, e.g., program code, from volatile data.